# Power BI topn function: Problem with topn function returning more than n rows due to duplicates

Tags: duplicates, powerbi, dax, top-n

This is the current data table that I have, which is called 'Potential High Usage'
[CLICK TO SEE DATA TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvgCT.png)

I tried to use the TOPN function to create a table of the top 10 'User ID' based on the 'Number of clicks'. This is how I tried to do it:

```
High Usage IDs = topn(10,'Potential High Usage',[Number of clicks])
```

The problem is that it returns 11 rows instead of 10. I am thinking that its because I have many duplicates for the least number of clicks that will still be considered as top 10 (Number of clicks = 2). I was wondering if there is a way to return ONLY 10 rows?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. TOPN will return more than N rows when there are ties at Nth row.
See the Microsoft TOPN dax function documentation.[image]

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to only return top 10 rows of the table? I tried sorting the table first then using topn, but it seems to ignore the sorting that I have done.

Answer (score 0):

First add index column using power query.
Then use following DAX to return top 10 rows.
[image]

Comment: this does not work for me as it is returning a table of the top 10 rows that is purely based on the assigned index, which is ignoring the "number of clicks" column that determines what the top 10 rows are.

Comment: First sort "number of clicks" column in ascending order then create index column then use the code.

Comment: sorry im really new to power BI. Actually, since my table is a calculated table, it does not show up in power query so i cannot click the "add index column". Is there a way for me to add the index column that you mentioned using DAX?

Comment: Not good solution but work around is copy calculated table using 3 dots in Data view and paste into excel then reload excel and insert index column in power query and use dax code.